# How to determine whether tkinter polygons collide?

Tags: python, tkinter, collision-detection

This is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import winsound
tk = Tk()

def key(event):
    inp = '' + event.char
    if inp == 'w':
        canvas.move(p1,0,-5)
        winsound.Beep(1000,50)
    if inp == 's':
        canvas.move(p1,0,5)
        winsound.Beep(1000,50)
    if inp == 'a':
        canvas.move(p1,-5,0)
        winsound.Beep(1000,50)
    if inp == 'd':
        canvas.move(p1,5,0)
        winsound.Beep(1000,50)

    if inp == 'i':
        canvas.move(p2,0,-5)
        winsound.Beep(700,50)
    if inp == 'k':
        canvas.move(p2,0,5)
        winsound.Beep(700,50)
    if inp == 'j':
        canvas.move(p2,-5,0)
        winsound.Beep(700,50)
    if inp == 'l':
        canvas.move(p2,5,0)
        winsound.Beep(700,50)

def callback(event):
    canvas.focus_set()



canvas = Canvas(tk, width=600, height=600)
canvas.bind("<Key>", key)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack()
p1 = canvas.create_polygon(10,10,20,10,15,0,fill='red')
p2 = canvas.create_polygon(510,10,520,10,515,0,fill='blue')
tk.update()


tk.mainloop()
```

I want to check if the polygons collide with each other and send a "game over" message when this happens
So I will do `print('you lost')` when they collide, but I don't know how to check for a collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas has a [find_overlapping](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) method which will return all items that overlaps a rectangular area. You can use the [bbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method) method to get the rectangular coordinates of a given player. If you have non-rectangular objects the collision detection won't be 100% precise, but it will probably be close enough.